# error: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe `va` with two column `vertex1` and `vertex2`. `va` has

```
6731710209 rows
```

I want to compute similarity between `vertex1` and `vertex2`. To do that I have the following UDF function:

```
weight_udf = udf(edgeWeight, FloatType())
va = va.withColumn('similarity', weight_udf(va.vertex1, va.vertex2))
```

When running the code I get the following strange error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b5fe21d0ba0, pid=67441, tid=0x00002b605e421700
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # J 12180 C2 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap$1.next()Z (60 bytes) @ 0x00002b5fe21d0ba0 [0x00002b5fe21d0ac0+0xe0]
    #
    # Core dump written. Default location: /project/6008168/moudi/job/core or core.67441
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /project/6008168/moudi/job/hs_err_pid67441.log
    [thread 47692633986816 also had an error]
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: what does the file `/project/6008168/tamouze/job/hs_err_pid67441.log` say?

Comment: it is a file of 2000 rows i cannot post here

Comment: *Heap Dump Analysis* - you will need to look up some articles on this or check some questions here on SO. maybe you will get some direction with this error as well. Also look up *Problematic Frame* and *Core dump* - `/project/6008168/moudi/job/core`